# Removing an element - optimized way

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the most efficient way in removing an element in DOM? (js or jquery)

> removeChild()

This is what I was using always. But, recently came across this

> The removed child node still exists in memory, but is no longer part
>   of the DOM.  With the first syntax-form shown, you may reuse the
>   removed node later in your code, via the oldChild object reference.

So, If I don't want to preserve the removed element in memory (for better performance), what is the best method?

Or like in java, if reference is null, is it automatically garbage collected and no need to worry about performance? I am asking this specifically as I am dealing with svg and many append/remove calls are made.

Comment: you are correct about null reference...would get garbage collected